# My app is not running on another device

Tags: java, android

I recently made a simple android app .Its working fine in my device but not running on any other phone when i share it via SHAREit or other means. I have already disabled Instant Run and I am currently working on API 22(Lollipop) and have tried it the phones with higher API's such as API 23 (Marshmallow). Can anybody please fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you share with SHAREit?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the app even start? What code crashes? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide some code and additional information.

Comment: Are you sharing signed build or debug build ?

Comment: `... Can anybody please fix it ...` Fix **what**? I see no code to fix.

Comment: Generate Signed apk.

Comment: probably runtime permissions might be causing this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Debug apk that is installed to the phone by Android studio will always gets some error when shared using SHAREit and similar softwares.

1. Bulid -> Rebuild Project
2. Bulid -> Build apk or Generate signed apk

Try sending the newly generated apk.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build options in toolbar and click on build APK. After that use that APK it works in all devices.